# Kotlin [ linked List] smart cast is impossible because of complex expression

Tags: kotlin

Background: it is a Linked List (ordering task for delivery), which involves different shopping carts. i need to write a function (fun sortByTotal) inside class OrderProcessing to do a sorting, so that the cart with highest price value can proceed the ordering first.

My difficulties are

> 1. how should i fix any of the errors in the function sortByTotal?

1.1 Error:(32, 51) Kotlin: Smart cast to 'OrderProcessing.OrderNode' is impossible, because 'run.next' is a complex expression

1.2 Error:(33, 20) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Double but Double.Companion was expected

1.3 Error:(34, 49) Kotlin: Smart cast to 'OrderProcessing.OrderNode' is impossible, because 'run.next' is a complex expression

1.4 Error:(38, 31) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: order
(may i know, why this "order" has error, but no error at line 32, 33?)

> 2. how can i link each shopping cart to OrderNode under OrderProcessing? each shopping cart info is not saved at the moment,
>      instead renew each time after "clear cart"

I understand that there are many mistakes, answer any part of them or give me some hints are already very appreciated. Thank you for the kindness.

my codes are as below:

```
 Class OrderProcessing {
        var first: OrderNode? = null
      // Linked List
        data class OrderNode(val order: Order, var next: OrderNode?)

    fun sortByTotal () {
    var run = first
        var temp = Double
            while (run?.next != null) {
    32        if (run.order.shoppingCart.totalprice  <= run.next.order.shoppingCart.totalprice){
    33            temp = run.order.shoppingCart.totalprice
    34            run.order.shoppingCart.totalprice = run.next.order.shoppingCart.totalprice
                run.next.order.shoppingCart.totalprice = temp
                }

    38        run?.next = OrderNode(order, run?.next)
            }
        }
```

Classes involved:

1.

```
Class ShoppingCart () {
    private val shoppingList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>
  // totalprice = sum of item price in each cart
   val totalprice : double
... }
```

2.

```
data class Order(
    val shoppingCart: ShoppingCart,
    val address: Address
)
```

3.

```
fun main(){

    // while loop until "exit", Menu with functions to add goods to cart, clear cart, show shopping list (items and price)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.1 Error:(32, 51) Kotlin: Smart cast to 'OrderProcessing.OrderNode' is impossible, because 'run.next' is a complex expression

Even though you check that `run?.next != null`, it's still possible that `next` will become `null` later. Adding non-null assertion would help: `run.next!!.order`

> 1.2 Error:(33, 20) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is Double but Double.Companion was expected

`var temp = Double`  - you assigned `Double` to your variable instead of declaring its type, you probably meant `var temp: Double`

> 1.4 Error:(38, 31) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: order

`run` is an instance of `OrderNode` which has `val order: Order`. `sortByTotal` is a method of `OrderProcessing`, there are no fields or local variables called `order`.

If you need to sort your custom linked list, then just swapping the shopping cart total prices (like you do in lines 33-35) is not a good idea, because it will keep `shoppingList` but mess the total prices. Instead you need to change `next` pointers accordingly. One possible way is to put all `OrderNode`s into a collection, then sort it by price and then iterate and reset `next` pointers for each `OrderNode`.

Comment: Thanks for your concise explanation, though cannot use the code, i still have learnt. may i ask, what does it mean "put all OrderNodes into a collection"?  OrderNodes is now a data class with a collection of orders. do i have any misunderstandings? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user12595983 each `OrderNode` has a reference to a next node only which makes it difficult to sort the entire list of nodes. You could try to implement your own sorting algorithm for your custom linked list (or look for [solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort-for-singly-linked-list/) on internet), or, as I suggested, just put all the `OrderNode`s into a standard Kotlin `List` one by one, then sort this list and reset the `next` references